# Possible to get blob of PDF that is currently edited in browser?

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-chrome-extension, browser, jspdf

Is there any possibility to get the blob of a PDF that is edited, I am able to get the original PDF sent by the server(which I have no control) but on that PDF, I want to place some text or edit it but I would like to get the blob of that edited PDF through someway so that I can send it further to my server. What are the possibilities to achieve something similar to this or using any JS PDF library or something if you have something sample work to do.

Comment: No, there's no such API.

Comment: @wOxxOm any work around possible? like any other hack

Comment: No, there isn't.